# Event from a Lightning Component has an event.target with DOM properties missing - what is going on?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

With this markup in a component:

```
<tr data-id="{! item.id }" onclick="{! c.rowSelect }">
    <td>{! item.name }</td>
    <td><ui:outputText value="{! item.type }"/></td>
    <td>{! item.phone }</td>
    ...
```

a click in the first or third `td` cell generates an `event` that has an `event.target` that has all the normal DOM properties such as `parentNode` and a `toString()` function that outputs:

> SecureElement: [object HTMLTableCellElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }

A click on the second `td` cell (that contains a component) generates an `event` that has an `event.target` that has **no properties** and a `toString()` function that outputs:

> SecureObject: [object HTMLSpanElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }

(The `span` appears to be a wrapper for the content emitted by the component.)

Can anyone explain what is going on - why the missing properties? Or at least suggest a way to get to the DOM `tr` element which is where the `Id` value I need for my logic is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties are missing because you are trying to reach into a component from a parent component, which is what Lightning is now trying to prevent you from doing.

It looks like the framework is happy to dispatch the event, but is not able to show you any info about it.

If you want to get the `{!item.type}` property, perhaps put it inside the `td` using a `data-item` property as well as inside the `ui:outputText`. That way you should be able to retrieve it.

However, you won't be able to retrieve it by using `event.target` - maybe you should put an onclick on that particular `td` and reference the `td` `data-item` property (don't forget to cancel the event if it comes from this td once you've caught it).

eg:

```
<td data-item="{! item.type}" onclick="{!c.rowSelect}"><ui:outputText value="{! item.type }"/></td>
```

Comment: Thanks: looks like swapping HTML for a component can prove painful. Can you confirm that there is nothing else in the `event` that helps? Will add extra code - just didn't want to do it without understanding the reason.

Comment: I'm not sure - I'll quickly spin up a cmp and check. But it's definitely encapsulation. You could also try to extend the `ui:outputText` and despatch your own click event... One thing I'm not sure how to do (or even if it's possible to do at all)  is to co-opt the lightning version of the native click event and add properties to that. That would be a nice solution.

Comment: The only property I want is the parentNode which references a node in my namespace; maybe one day that will be exposed.

Comment: I've just confirmed that there is pretty much nothing on that event that you can use, if from the `ui:inputText`. It looks like the data-item plan is probably your best bet at the moment. And yes, parentNode is pretty much all you'd need eh!